# Shortcut to the second instance of a class in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bit of a problem where I have to link to particular sections within a web page over which I have no control.

Rather than having lots of nice, unique elements so I can just use www.thepage.com#yayforcss, this page instead has multiple instances of the same element.

Is there any way to link to the xth instance of a class in a web page?

Comment: Not with CSS - You need Javascript / or a JS library.

Comment: <div class='item'">xxxx</div>
<div class='item'">yyyyy</div>
<div class='item'">zzzzz</div>
is there any way I can go straight to the z line?

A javascript solution would be fine too.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances of the same element"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (at least without using some massive JS code) to use same ID over multiple elements and to point to the correct element using URLs with hashtag.

> ### W3.org html and css specifications about IDs
>
> 1. The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element (which may be verified by an SGML parser). - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
> 2. What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such attributes can have the same value; whatever the document language, an ID attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element. - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors

If you want to have direct links to specific parts of the content - use unique IDs for every section:

```
<div id="section_1">some content</div>
<div id="section_2">some content</div>
<div id="section_3">some content</div>
<div id="section_4">some content</div>
```

And then access this sections with:

```
www.example.com/page/#section_1
www.example.com/page/#section_2
www.example.com/page/#section_3
www.example.com/page/#section_4
```

If you have CSS styles that apply to your current ID - you have to change that and use classes.

Comment: But the OP did not say that he had duplicate IDs. He said he had multiple elements with the same class, and wanted to jump to the second instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to jump from one page to the nth instance of a particular class on some other page, the simple answer is **you can't**. For that, you would have to have IDs.

If you want to jump within the same page, then there is a relative easy way. Use `getElementByClassNames` to get the elements with a particular class, then use `scrollIntoView` to jump to that element.

```
function scroll_to_nth_of(class_name, n) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(class_name)[n].scrollIntoView();
}
```

Then

```
<a onclick="scroll_to_nth_of('my-class', 1)">Show me the second my-class!</a>
```

or equivalent.

In Chrome, you could use `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded`. Whereas `scrollIntoView` will always pop the element to the very top of the page (or bottom, if you pass it a parameter of false), `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` will not scroll at all if the element is already visible somewhere on the page.

By the way, CSS has nothing to do with this problem. You can indeed use CSS to target elements on a page, but strictly in order to apply styling to them, not to jump to them.